# Como adicionar valores á uma coluna excel pelo python

Tags: python

Boa tarde, estou tentando alterar a idade das pessoas na lista abaixo que vem de um excel, porem ao alterar, o ultimo valor se repete para todas as outras linhas... segue o código:

TABELA:

```
       NOME  IDADE  teste
0    THIAGO     22      0
1    MARCOS     23      0
2      JOAO     27      0
3  VINICIUS     33      0
4    CARLOS     45      0
```

CÓDIGO:

```
import pandas as pd
ex = pd.read_excel('EXCEL.xlsx')
ex['teste'] = 0

for i, p in enumerate(ex['teste']):
    cont = 0
    if i == 0:
        ex['teste'] = int(input('Digite a idade: '))
        cont += 1
    else:
        ex['teste'] = int(input('Digite a idade: '))
        cont += 1

print(ex)
```

Comment: O problema está na atribuição. `ex["teste"] = VALOR` irá atribuir o valor à TODA coluna `teste`. Você quer atribuir um valor para cada linha manualmente? Outra coisa: para que o if/else uma vez que fazem a mesma coisa?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode iterar sobre o data frame e utilizar o .loc para atribuir novos valores:

```
import pandas as pd

nome = ['THIAGO','MARCOS','JOAO','VINICIUS','CARLOS']
idade  = [22, 23, 27, 33, 45]

ex = pd.DataFrame({'NOME': nome, 'IDADE': idade})
ex['Teste'] = 0
display(ex)
```

| NOME | IDADE | Teste |
| --- | --- | --- |
| THIAGO | 22 | 0 |
| MARCOS | 23 | 0 |
| JOAO | 27 | 0 |
| VINICIUS | 33 | 0 |
| CARLOS | 45 | 0 |

Depois iteramos:

```
for index, row in ex.iterrows():
    ex.loc[index, 'Teste'] = input('Digite a idade: ')

Digite a idade: 10
Digite a idade: 20
Digite a idade: 30
Digite a idade: 40
Digite a idade: 50
```

| NOME | IDADE | Teste |
| --- | --- | --- |
| THIAGO | 22 | 10 |
| MARCOS | 23 | 20 |
| JOAO | 27 | 30 |
| VINICIUS | 33 | 40 |
| CARLOS | 45 | 50 |